# ES2017 Async/await functions - do they work only with promises?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-2017

I started using `async/await` ES7 functions in my js applications (transpiled by Babel).

Correct me if wrong, but do they work only with Promises? If yes, this means that I need to wrap regular callback functions into Promises (what I'm currently doing btw).

Comment: It also works with thenables :-)

Comment: @Bergi are thenables a superset of promises? I'd never considered them as separate entities.

Comment: @Bergi which are promises :)

Comment: @Mathletics: Yes, [exactly](https://promisesaplus.com/). Thenables are objects with a `then` method of unknown functionality and origin.

Comment: Yes, you can also wait for non-promise values, the spec literally says `Promise.resolve` will be called on the value so plain values will remain plain values and thenables will be converted to promises in a safe way. A `then`able means you can assimilate promises from different libraries in `await`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: What does it mean to say "thenables will be converted to promises" when the preceding comments seem to clarify that thenables already *are* promises?

Comment: @hippietrail All promises are thenables, but not all thenables are promises.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current (and likely final) async/await proposal awaits promises and desugars into something like bluebird's `Promise.coroutine` with `await` playing the part of `yield`.

This makes sense, as promises represent a value + time and you're waiting for that value to become available. Note `await` also waits for promise like constructs in all other languages that include it like C# or Python (3.5+) .

Note that converting callback APIs to promises is very easy, and some libraries offer tools to do so in a single command. See [How to convert an existing callback API to promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's easy to switch, my confusion was because of see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294521/es7-async-await-functions-do-they-work-only-with-promises/31294633#comment50580127_31294633

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you `await` a promise.

```
async function myFunction() {
  let result = await somethingThatReturnsAPromise();
  console.log(result); // cool, we have a result
}
```

http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html

Comment: I just noticed that if you're using request https://github.com/request/request and doing `await request.get('url')` it will return response body. Does it mean that request lib methods not only callback based?

Comment: @Kosmetika you can not await the request library directly, but you can easily `promisifyAll` it and use it with promises with very low performance overhead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum but it awaits without promisifying that caused my confusion!

Comment: @Kosmetika no, it really doesn't - http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=function%20fn(cb)%7B%0A%20%20setTimeout(()%3D%3E%20cb(null%2C%203)%2C%201000)%3B%0A%7D%0Aasync%20function%20foo()%7B%0A%20%20let%20val%20%3D%20await%20fn()%3B%0A%20%20console.log(typeof%20val%2C%20val)%3B%0A%20%20%0A%7D%0Afoo()%3B what happened is that `request` was probably promisified before by a library that wraps APIs for you like bluebird.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum strange days strange ways.. :)